# Trying to Convert xsd schema to a class

Tags: c#, api, class, xsd, schema

I am trying to create a class based on an xsd schema from a football api site that I can then use to take different properties from the actual feed.

This is a sample of the schema
http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd

This is an example of the feed

http://developer.sportsdatallc.com/files/soccer_v2_standings.xml

I am trying to convert an xsd schema to a class file.

Basically I have saved the xsd file and tried using xsd.exe to create a class. When I run it however I got a bucket load of errors and I've no idea what they mean.

On my Console Application I want it to act as a client, connect to the data feed and store an object for each league and whoever is currently rank 1 in that league.

CMD Errors

```
    C:\Users\Daniel\Documents>xsd /c teams-standing.xsd
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.33440]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: Could not find file "./common-soccer.xsd".
Schema validation warning: Undefined complexType 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/s
chema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd:simpleCategory' is used as a base for comp
lex type extension. Line 27, position 14.
Schema validation warning: Undefined complexType 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/s
chema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd:extendedTournamentGroup' is used as a base
 for complex type extension. Line 37, position 14.
Schema validation warning: Undefined complexType 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/s
chema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd:extendedTournament' is used as a base for
complex type extension. Line 49, position 14.
Schema validation warning: Undefined complexType 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/s
chema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd:simpleTeam' is used as a base for complex
type extension. Line 61, position 14.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'teams-standing'.
  - The datatype 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standin
g.xsd:simpleCategory' is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

C:\Users\Daniel\Documents>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not work as you described. You downloaded only one file when the whole set includes many more files.

[image]

These files are all in the same folder on the HTTP server. Download them all *in the same folder* on your machine; for each file in the diagram below, concatenate http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/soccer/sr/v2/ with the name of the file and download it; then try your command again (it worked for me).